# What would be the time complexity of an if statement?

Tags: c, big-o

Below I have an algorithm that is meant to return an integer value that represents the height of a binary tree and I have been asked to find out what the time complexity of it would be, here is the code:

```
struct Node {
     int data;
     struct Node *left;
     struct Node *right; }

 int FindHeight(struct Node *root) {
     if (root == NULL)
           return -1;
     return max(FindHeight(root->1eft),FindHeight(root->right)) +1; 
}
```

I'm I right in thinking that this would be 0(1)?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not just `if`-statement. It is `max` with recursive call.

For your code, the recursion go through all nodes. It goes through each node once so the time complexity is linear `O(n)`.

The depth of recursion may vary depending on tree structure. If tree is degenerated the memory complexity `O(n)`. In case of balanced tree, memory complexity is `O(ln(n))`.

Comment: Actually this algorithm is O(n) for all trees.